# How to add encryption-provider-config option to kube-apiserver?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am using kubernetes 1.15.7 version.

I am trying to follow the link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/#understanding-the-encryption-at-rest-configuration to enable 'encryption-provider-config' option on 'kube-apiserver'.

I edited file '/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml' and provided below option

```
- --encryption-provider-config=/home/rtonukun/secrets.yaml
```

But after that I am getting below error.

```
The connection to the server 171.69.225.87:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

with all kubectl commands like 'kubectl get no'.

Mainy, how do I do these below two steps?

```
3. Set the --encryption-provider-config flag on the kube-apiserver to point to the location of the config file.

4. Restart your API server.
```

Comment: Are trying to apply this configuration in a new cluster or on a cluster previously created ?

Comment: Previously created cluster

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've reproduced exactly your scenario, and I'll try to explain how I fixed it

#### Reproducing the same scenario

1. Create the encrypt file on `/home/koopakiller/secrets.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apiserver.config.k8s.io/v1
kind: EncryptionConfiguration
resources:
  - resources:
    - secrets
    providers:
    - aescbc:
        keys:
        - name: key1
          secret: r48bixfj02BvhhnVktmJJiuxmQZp6c0R60ZQBFE7558=
    - identity: {}
```

Edit the file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` and set the `--encryption-provider-config` flag:

```
   - --encryption-provider-config=/home/koopakiller/encryption.yaml
```

Save the file and exit.

When I checked the pods status got the same error:

```
$ kubectl get pods -A
The connection to the server 10.128.0.62:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

#### Troubleshooting

Since kubectl is not working anymore, I tried to look directly the running containers using docker command, then I see kube-apiserver container was recently recreated:

```
$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
54203ea95e39        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 1 minutes ago       Up 1 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-lab-1_kube-system_015d9709c9881516d6ecf861945f6a10_0
...
```

Kubernetes store the logs of created pods on `/var/log/pods` directory, I've checked the kube-apiserver log file and found a valuable information:

> {"log":"Error: error opening encryption provider configuration file "/home/koopakiller/encryption.yaml": open **/home/koopakiller/encryption.yaml: no such file or directory**\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-01-22T13:28:46.772768108Z"}

#### Explanation

Taking a look at manifest file `kube-apiserver.yaml` is possible to see the command `kube-apiserver`, it runs into container, so they need to have the `encryption.yaml` file mounted into container.

If you check the `volumeMounts` in this file, you could see that only the paths below is mounted in container by default:

> - /etc/ssl/certs
> - /etc/ca-certificates
> - /etc/kubernetes/pki
> - /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
> - /usr/share/ca-certificates

```
    ...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
          name: ca-certs
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/ca-certificates
          name: etc-ca-certificates
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
          name: k8s-certs
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
          name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
          name: usr-share-ca-certificates
          readOnly: true
    ...
```

Based on the facts above, we can assume that apiserver failed to start because `/home/koopakiller/encryption.yaml` doesn't actually mounted into container.

#### How to solve

I can see 2 ways to solve this issue:

**1st** - Copy the encryption file to `/etc/kubernetes/pki` (or any of the path above) and change the path in `/etc/kubernetes/kube-apiserver.yaml`:

```
   - --encryption-provider-config=/etc/kubernetes/encryption.yaml
```

Save the file and wait apiserver restart.

**2nd** - Create a new `volumeMounts` in the kube-apiserver.yaml manifest to mount a custom directory from node into container.

Let's create a new directory in `/etc/kubernetes/secret` (home folder isn't a good location to leave config files =)).

Edit `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`:

```
...
    - --encryption-provider-config=/etc/kubernetes/secret/encryption.yaml
...
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/secret
      name: secret
      readOnly: true
...
  volumes:
    - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/secret
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: secret
...
```

After save the file kubernetes will mount the node path `/etc/kubernetes/secret` into the same path into the apiserver container, wait start completely and try to list your node again.

Please let know if that helped!

Comment: Thanks for your ans. After doing all these changes secret should be encrypted right . I able to see the secret plain text values after running this cmd  ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key get /registry/secrets/default/secret1

Comment: It worked. - identity: {} should be kept at last. I had placed it above key.